# JavaScript regexp to matching heart emoji character behaves weirdly

Tags: javascript, regex, browser

```
var a="❤️";
console.log(a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
console.log(/^[\u2000-\u3300]$/.test(a));      // false
console.log(/^[\u2000-\u3300]/.test(a));     // true
```

Don't understand why 2 regex tests behaving differently and this is happening only for this character.

Comment: Maybe because heart is beating? ;-)

Comment: as @CertainPerformance mentioned, it's because that string is two characters, but I thought I'd describe why. One is for the heart `"❤️"[0]`, the other is for the variation. `'\ufe0f' == "❤️"[1]` seems to be the only modifier for that heart though. So this is going to be slightly harder than a single range given there *are* other hearts `/^[\u2000-\u3300]/.test('')`. The best example of variations are the skin tones `'' + '\uD83C\uDFFF'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`❤️` is composed of *two* code points, so the `$` anchor after matching just one character will fail:

```js
var a="❤️";
console.log(a.charCodeAt(0));
console.log(a.charCodeAt(1));
```

For an example of a pattern that will pass:

```js
var a="❤️";
console.log(a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
console.log(a.charCodeAt(1).toString(16));
console.log(/^[\u2000-\u3300][\u2000-\uff00]$/.test(a));
```